# spring data neo4j ignoring @Transient hibernate annotation?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, hibernate-annotations, spring-data-neo4j

In one of my pojo i have used

```
    @RelatedTo(type = "User")
    @Transient
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
```

which is not mapped with Hibernate, to make hibernate ignore this i have used @Transient, otherwise i am getting `Unknown field users` but now `neo4j` is also ignoring the field. It is not storing the relationship. If i remove `@Transient` `neo4j` is working fine, but Hibernate is giving execption.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the @NodeEntity annotation with the "partial" argument? This is required for cross-store setups, have a look at the manual: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#reference:cross-store